# Is bootstrap Studentized pivotal interval always better ?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I am trying to do exercice 6 of chapter 3 in "All of non parametric statistics" by Wasserman which consists in evaluating the 4 type of bootstrap intervals (normal, percentile, pivotal, studentized) for log-normal samples and the estimator of skewness.

**what I did :**

- For a given n, I draw normal samples Y_i, take X_i = exp(Y_i)
- Run bootstrap (by drawing a sample of size n with replacement from the original data X)
- Compute the four 95% confidence intervals. For the studentized interval, as suggested in the book, I estimated the standard error for each bootstrap replication using the non-parametric delta method.
- For each intervals, check if the true value of skewness is inside the intervals or not. I do that a lot of times and count how often the interval was good or not. When n->infinity, the proportion should tend to 95%.

For the log-normal distribution, here are the evolution of this proportion when n is increasing
[image: log_normal]

The four interval are not very good but the studentized interval is the better.

I then tried to do the same with normal distribution. And here is what I get 
[image: normal_CI]

The studentized CI seems to be the less good (and it does not seem to increase).

**So my questions are :**

- Is this behaviour normal/possible ?
- Do you think that it more probably means that I made some error in my simulations ? (I can naturally show the code if somebody is interested)

Thanks for your help !